# How can I compare two arrays and get the data that do not fit in the arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays right now, how can i get the difference between 2 arrays?

```
foreach($test1 as $array)
{
    if (!isset($result[$array["id"]])) $result[$array["id"]] = $array["date"];
}
foreach ($result as $id => $date) {
    $new1[] = array("id" => $id, "date" => $date);
}
```

Gives me this output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 11-02-13 05:36:32 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 42415 [date] => 12-02-13 13:56:48 )
```

_

```
foreach($test2 as $array) {
    if (!isset($result[$array["id"]])) $result[$array["id"]] = $array["date"];
}
foreach ($result as $id => $date) {
    $new2[] = array("id" => $id, "date" => $date);
}
```

Gives me this output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 47523 [date] => 12-02-13 14:22:14 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 42135[date] => 02-02-13 14:51:42 )
```

Now i want to compare them so i can get the difference out: I would like that the expected output as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 42415 [date] => 12-02-13 13:56:48 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 42135[date] => 02-02-13 14:51:42)
```

Comment: what have you tried? there are lots of `array_xxx()` functions built into PHP; have you tried any of them? what results have you had?

Comment: almost all of them. :/

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: So what? Taking my answer in [How can I remove duplicates in an array like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14835280/revisions) and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>

Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```